# Access resx in application from Silverlight class library

Tags: silverlight-4.0, resx, xap

Resource files in Silverlight can be accessed using the code below:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("MyLibraryNamespace.MyFolder.MyResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

However in my application this piece of code is not in the application itself, but in a Silverlight class library and the app has reference to it; changing the namespace to the "MyAppNamespace" just generates error.

How can I reach the resources in the xap file from the Silverlight class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what I wanted I had to do the following:

```
var assembly = Application.Current.GetType().Assembly;
```

And after that I can create ResourceManager with the resources like this:

```
var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(name, assembly);
```

where name is the path from my first post.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice video here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh336287

The trick is to write a "proxy" class so that you can reference strings from XAML. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28VS.92%29.aspx):

```
public class LocalizedStrings {
  public LocalizedStrings() { }
  private static sdkGlobalizationCS.AppResources localizedResources = new sdkGlobalizationCS.AppResources();
  public sdkGlobalizationCS.AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return localizedResources; } }
}
```

And in XAML (after adding the class in the static resources):

```
<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.LangRegionNameFrFR, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for not being specific. I can access the resources from my XAML with binding, I know how to do that. The point is that I can only do it if my code is in the application. If I put that code in a Silverlight class library I can no longer access these resources (which still remain in the application); I am trying with

ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager(             "/AppNamespace;component/Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

but this doesn't do it either - in fact this code does not work even in the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dario Solera, It solved my problem and in most easy way.

Answer (score 1):

This is good and I was able to do the same.

In my case I have the same library shared between applications so I extract dynamically the name of the assembly:

```cs
var ast = assembly.FullName;
char[] delimit = new char[] { ',' };
string[] parts = ast.Split(delimit);
var gResources = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(parts[0]+"resource path here", assembly);
```