# Access Application Localization resources (resx) from Library

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, localization, resources, shared-libraries

I've seen the solution suggested here: [Access resx in application from Silverlight class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384851/access-resx-in-application-from-silverlight-class-library/10257261#10257261)
and it works for the resources itself.

My problem is slightly different:

1. I have 2 apps that use the same library. They are localized so I have a resource folder and in the folder of the apps the files AppResource.resx, AppResource.it-IT.resx
2. I have a library that includes XAML files and code as well. It is localized so I have a resource folder and in the folder of the apps the files LibResource.resx, LibResource.it-IT.resx
3. The app is using the MvvmLight libraries. As suggested I've extended the class
   ViewModelBase in a ViewModelBaseExtended adding the fields:

```cs
public class ViewModelBaseExtended : ViewModelBase
{
    private static LibResources resources = new LibResources();
    public LibResources Resources { get { return resources; } }
}
```

4. The XAML in the library is able to access correctly the localized resources:

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="PhoneClassLibrary1.MainPage"
           DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
Grid.Row="0"
Margin="24,24,0,12">
           <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle"
                Text="{Binding Resources.AppName}"
                Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
           <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle"
                Text="{Binding Resources.LocalLib}"
                Margin="-3,-8,0,0"
                Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />
</StackPanel>
```

My problem is: how can I access from the library the AppResources in the application?
I cannot refer to them directly Namespace.AppResources as the library is shared between applications and Namespace is not defined at design time and changes at run time.

I have a full project ready to test with the exact configruation, files etxc.. all working apart from the access from library to application level.

Applying the solution I mentioned in the beginning:

```cs
private static AppResources _gResources;
public AppResources gResources { set {_gResources = value;}  get { return _gResources; } }

public ViewModelBaseExtended()
{
    var assembly = Application.Current.GetType().Assembly;
    var ast = assembly.FullName;
    char[] delimit = new char[] { ',' };
    string[] parts = ast.Split(delimit);

    gResources = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(parts[0]+ ".AppResources", assembly);
}
```

I correctly does not compile with an error as gResources is an AppResource (or LibResource) class while ResourceManager returns a different object.

Comment: Please note that I was able to extract a single value from the App resources with `gAppName = gResources.GetString("AppName");` but I want to access all of them

Comment: How did you solve this ? i have posted the same query here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090589/localizing-appresources